# "Could not read from remote repository" -- Git push issues from a repository I created

Tags: github, git-push, git-remote

I am relatively new at using Git, and am trying to push files from my computer to a public repository I created.

My terminal continues to recognize that the 'remote origin' already exists after I've added it, but refuses my requests to push the code when I use the 'git push -u origin master' command.

It gives me the response:

'fatal: git@github.com/ccepelak/filename.git does not appear to be a repository. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.'

I've deleted and recreated both repository and file folders to try this process from the beginning multiple times, and it still gives me this error--- What's the deal?

I've looked at the other Stack Overflow questions with similar titles, and none seem to be addressing the same issue I'm experiencing here. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: First you clone (or checkout if already cloned) a remote repo and then push from the local copy. From you description, however it's not very clear what steps exactly you were doing in what order, it appears that your local is not a clone of the remote.

Comment: Can you include the commands and their output in your terminal from the beginning (starting with clone) until you get the error?